# Install Pop!_OS in custom mode with encrypted root partition

Tags: system-installation, grub, luks, initramfs, pop-os

I've tried to install Pop!_OS in custom mode because I need Multiboot, but I also want an encrypted root partition. So I set an /boot/efi partition and unlocked a previous with luks2 encrypted and ext4 formatted partition and selected it as root partition. After that, I finished the installation as usual. But when I restart the computer to finish the installation, it only boots into busy box. So I booted the live version to mount the unlocked root partition to /mnt/temp to check /etc/crypttab which was empty and in /etc/fstab was the UUID of the unlocked partition. So I tried to fix it by editing the crypttab and run `apt install cryptsetup-initramfs` and `update-initramfs -u` in the bash after `chroot /mnt/temp /bin/bash -i` but update-initramfs shows a bunch of python like errors. Has anybody ideas to successfully install Pop!_OS with an encrypted root partition in the custom installation mode?